# Crystal Reports in VS2010: Prompted Parameter value in Design Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report and in design time on VS2010 I apply a parameter field via the [Database Expert][Add cmd][create parameter] wizard. But this prompts me for a specific value for my new parameter. I don't see why it should as its going to be dynamic!

In my c# code, my solution only works if the dynamic value at run time matches the design-time prompted value. This seems to defeat the purpose.

In my run-time code I have:
 crystalReport.SetParameterValue("TenantID", tenantID);

TenanID is the CR parameter in design time
tenanID is the picked up dynamic value

Can't i make this truly dynamic?

Comment: The error i get is "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The system cannot find the path specified.\r"

Comment: They are both numbers. I don't know how to remove the default value  - you mean in the CR design mode on VS2010?

Comment: It won't let me leave the value blank.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 crystalReport.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue (num)
```

where "**num**" is your parameter value

Comment: Its not allowing me use ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue so I tried this but with no luck: Param.ParameterFieldName = "TenantID";
            myDiscreteValue.Value = tenantID;
            myParam.CurrentValues.Add(myDiscreteValue);
            crystalReport.ParameterFields.Add(myParam);